# How to get translation and roation data using 6DOF MPU6150

Tags: algorithms, filter-design, motion-detection, motion

I am trying to get the position data from an IMU 6 Degrees of Freedom ([MPU-6150](http://store.explorelabs.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=12&products_id=142)) board using an Arduino Uno. I am trying Jeff Rowberg’s example MPU6050_DMP6.ino that may be found [here](http://store.explorelabs.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=12&products_id=142).

This is the first time I am working with an IMU. I have no idea whether it's possible to get the position data using the using quaternions and yaw, pitch and roll data? It would be great if someone can explain how to find the position of the sensor (translation in cm or mm and rotation in degrees) using that sketch.